# How to use XQuery for this XML

Tags: sql-server, xquery

This is my sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <string>EBITDA</string>
  <string>Products Revenue</string>
</Root>
```

I try to parse the XML this way using `xquery`.

```
declare @xmldata xml =N'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <string>EBITDA</string>
  <string>Products Revenue</string>
</Root>'

Declare @cnt INT = @xmldata.value('count(/Root/string)', 'INT')     
print @cnt
```

How to parse the above sample XML by `xquery`?

### EDIT

```
declare @xmldata xml =N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <string>EBITDA</string>
  <string>Products Revenue</string>
</Root>'

Declare @i INT, @cnt INT = @xmldata.value('count(/Root/string)', 'INT')     

DECLARE @LineItem VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @i = 1      
WHILE @i <= @cnt      
BEGIN     

SELECT @LineItem = col.value('(string/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/Root/string[position() = sql:variable("@i")]') AS tab (col);   

PRINT @LineItem

SET @i=@i+1
END
```

My line item is not getting printed from while loop. Wwhat is wrong in the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465352/1068246

Comment: So you're getting `XML parsing: line 2, character 6, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input`, right? The `<?` characters should be the first characters in the string - don't start with a blank line.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for your help. i change the xml and it worked. i gave my full code in Edit section. there i mention my line item is not getting printed from while loop. what is wrong there? can you please guide me.

Comment: @MuzafferGALATA i check your link. i follow their approach and when i try to read string value like this way `@LineItem = col.value('(/Root/string/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  ` then only first value comes twice because there is 2 records in xml. only first value is getting read not second one. what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` statement doesn't print null values. Because `tab (col)` is already referencing a `/Root/string` node the `col.value('(string/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')` function returns null.

If you restructure your code like this you'll get the desired print result...

```sql
declare @xmldata xml =N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <string>EBITDA</string>
  <string>Products Revenue</string>
</Root>'

Declare @i INT, @cnt INT = @xmldata.value('count(/Root/string)', 'INT')     

DECLARE @LineItem VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @i = 1      
WHILE @i <= @cnt      
BEGIN     

SELECT @LineItem = col.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/Root/string[position() = sql:variable("@i")]') AS tab (col);   

PRINT @LineItem

SET @i=@i+1
END
```

```
EBITDA
Products Revenue
```

If you want to consume the results in something else, though, you could return a result set like this:

```sql
declare @xmldata xml =N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <string>EBITDA</string>
  <string>Products Revenue</string>
</Root>';

select col.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as LineItem
from @xmldata.nodes('/Root/string') as tab (col);
```

```
LineItem
----------------
EBITDA
Products Revenue

(2 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
 DECLARE @companyxml xml =
'<Root>
  <string>EBITDA</string>
  <string>Products Revenue</string>
</Root>';


SELECT x.XmlCol.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') AS CompanyName
  FROM @companyxml.nodes('/Root/string') x (XmlCol);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this `(.)` ?

Comment: unnecessary. I've removed it. I had found it from a sample and I did not delete it because worked.